# Can't see any invocation logs in GCP Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

When running GCP Cloud Function, I don't see any logs in the console.
I do see only function has been updated logs but I expect to see also function invocation logs and my function internal logs.

I tied several options and all end up with the same outcome:

1. Python3.8 - gen1
2. Python3.8 - gen1
3. Node - gen1
4. Node - gen2

For all the gen2, there were no logs also at CloudRun log console.

The code for node it is simply the default with console.info:

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('helloHttp', (req, res) => {
 console.info("hello from gen2")       
 res.send(`Hello ${req.query.name || req.body.name || 'World'}!`);
});
```

[image: the logs from the console]
There are only logs regarding the Update and not from the function itself.

I see some posts about this issue has been resolved, but it I face it again.

Thanks all

Comment: Did you search with Cloud Logging? If so, what's you filter?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere,
the filter is 

resource.type = "cloud_function"
resource.labels.function_name = "function-2"
resource.labels.region = "us-central1"
severity=(DEFAULT OR DEBUG OR INFO OR NOTICE OR WARNING OR ERROR OR CRITICAL OR ALERT OR EMERGENCY)

and the returned methodName are :  

google.cloud.functions.v2.FunctionService.CreateFunction, google.cloud.functions.v2.FunctionService.UpdateFunction

Comment: can you refer to this [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging/issues/633) and [answer](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging), is it helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav, unfortunately it wasn't helpful. I tried the examples and can't see the logs yet. I am definitely missing something

Comment: have a look at this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging) is it helpful?

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't aware that there was a logging sink filtering in my project.
There is an option to send logs only from specific services. At my case, Functions wasn't included.

Comment: Thank you for this - I had been looking all over and didn't think to take off this filter.